# Recursive definition of a vector

Tags: function, recursion, for-loop, wolfram-mathematica, iteration

I would like to define a list using a for loop and I need to do it using a function of the n-iterate.
I have:

Initialization

```
In[176]:  Subscript[y, 0] = {1, 2, 3}

Out[180]:  {1,2,3}
```

The function:

```
In[181]:  F[n_] := For[l = 1, l++, l <= 3, Subscript[y, n + 1][[l]] :=Subscript[y, n][[l]]+ n]
```

I call the function

```
F[0]
```

and I get:

```
In[183]:   Subscript[y, 1]

Out[183]:  Subscript[0, 1]
```

I should have `{1,2,3}`.

Anyone know why it isn't working as it should?

Answer (score 0):

I have troubles recreating your error, problem.

I understand you want to add `n` to your vector, where `n` is the number of the subscript.

Here's another way to have a go at your question, avoiding the loop and the subscripts:

```
Clear@y;
y[0] = {1, 2, 3};
y[n_Integer] : =y[n - 1] + n
```

(as `Plus` is `Listable`, you can just add `n` to the vector, avoiding the `For`)

and then call it using, e.g.

```
y[0]
{1,2,3}
```

or

```
y[5]
{16,17,18}
```

Alternatively, using memoization, you could define `y` as follows:

```
y[n_Integer] := y[n] = y[n - 1] + n
```

This will then store already calculated values (check `?y` after executing e.g. y[5]). Don't forget to `Clear` `y`, if `y` changes.

Obviously, for a function as this one, you might want to consider:

```
y[n_Integer] := y[0] + Total[Range[n]]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, you're right. In this case it works fine in the other way you wrote, but this was a simplified case of my real problem, just to try to understand what was my mistake.

My problem is to create a succession of partitions of a dataset, so I need to calculate the information gain for every subset. That's why I need to use the for loop to apply the function to every subset of the list. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500401/how-to-create-a-succession-of-best-partitions-of-a-dataset

If you'd like to help, that'd be great !

Comment: do you really want to use `Subscript`?